# How to send parallel POST requests Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am currently trying to load test a server. Due to issues outside of my control, I cannot use jmeter for my testing. What would be the best way to create a set of threads and have each one send a post at the same moment, or as close as I can get to it? My current implementation creates a number of threads with a for loop before running the method which sends to POST to the server. But this isn't concurrent at all.

Comment: i don't see how jmeter is related to the architecture

Comment: If you're load testing the server from outside (simulating HTTP traffic), it shouldn't matter how the traffic is generated. So why is JMeter out of the question?

Comment: I can't say specifically. But there is a way I am handling data that jmeter cannot do. That isn't the important part.

Comment: Id say you would want to do this in a cluster, and not in multiple threads on the same machine unless you have a machine with several NICs. Your bottleneck isnt the cores, its your NIC. Your NIC will still empty its buffer sequentially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Id say you would want to do this in a cluster, and not in multiple threads on the same machine unless you have a machine with several network interface cards (NICs). Your bottleneck isnt the cores, its your NIC. Your NIC will still empty its buffer sequentially.

What I would recommend is having a cluster of as many machines as you can. On each machine, have a couple threads (just to ensure the NIC's buffer stays full). Don't bother synchronizing the cluster to send requests at the same time, because the round trip time (RTT) will take too long and it will void your load testing. Just have each Thread hammer away...statistically speaking, you're bound to get a couple POST requests at the same time, provided your cluster is sufficiently large.

Comment: Assuming for whatever crazy reason exists I can't use a pre-existing load app, this is what I would do with the app I would create.  Put the jar on as many machines as possible and run them in parallel.

Comment: A NIC can only handle a single connection at a time to a host?

Comment: a NIC has a buffer, and you can fill it as fast as you want, but it can only empty the buffer to send packets sequentially. Servers get around this by having multiple NICs - not that I'm a server guru or anything

Comment: It may send packets sequentially, but those packets are not necessarily sequential.  So the host receives them in a quasi-parallel manner.

Comment: T1 generates packet 1.  T2 generates packet 2.  NIC sends 1, 2.  That's effectively parallel.

Comment: Right. It depends on the route that the nodes along the way choose, but the originator NIC is still a bit of a bottleneck that, while it doesn't care about packet collision or packet loss or anything else, it still can only send packets one at a time. To get more than one packet sent in parallel, you need multiple NICs - which usually is easiest through multiple nodes. The OP wants to load test his machine, which means its not really relevant how you can generate packets in parallel, its only relevant that the packets are sent in parallel...if that makes sense.

Comment: @searchengine27 When you say "his machine" are you referring to the server I am hitting with my requests?

Comment: Yes. I think that last sentence might have been unclear. Let's call the machine you're testing on Server1, and the machine's you're generating the POST requests on NodeA, NodeB,...,NodeZ. You want to send packets in parallel from NodeA, NodeB,...,NodeZ to sufficiently saturate the NIC of Server1.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming yhis question is just about synchronizing your threads, and not creating/running threads, then I recommend a [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).  The example in the link is great.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, OP is asking about load testing with POST requests.  All clients requests should be autonomous and the server should already be functionally tested.  Therefore, synchronization would not be under consideration.

Comment: "My current implementation creates a number of threads with a for loop before running the method which sends to POST to the server. But this isn't concurrent at all."  Sounds like synchronization problem.

Comment: OK, I can see that if he's bothering to synchronize on some shared connection or something, but there shouldn't be any shared resources at all between the threads, hence the reason I'm saying it doesn't deal with synchronization.

Comment: You are correct. Looking into the example you provided it seems that this would work best for what I need to do. But searchengine27's answer also seems useful. Should I not even bother with synchronization if I plan to put the jar on several machines and have each one send hundreds of requests to one server?

Comment: @drpogue Correct.  I would not bother with synchronization -- assuming you are not trying to share something between threads.  And I don't see why you would.

Comment: @MadConan Interesting. No the only thing I am trying to do is see how many concurrent operations does it take before my servers fail, which was why my first thought was jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend using some load testing application framework.  There are many to choose from.

With that said, you could use something like this to start with.  This would be where I would start from.  You would need to implement the `performRequest` method.  This is not very robust, to say the least.  There is no logging, no reporting no error handling -- all of which you get "for free" (for certain definitions of "free") with a load testing application.

```
public class HttpClient {
    enum RequestType{
        POST,GET
    }

    private RequestType type;
    private String url;

    public HttpClient(RequestType rt, String url){
        type = rt;
        this.url = url;
    }

    public void performRequest(){
       // your code here.
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<HttpClient> clients = new ArrayList<>();
        int clientCount = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        String url = args[1];
        for(int i=0; i<clientCount; i++){
            clients.add(new HttpClient(RequestType.POST,url));
        }
        clients.parallelStream().forEach(HttpClient::performRequest);
    }
}
```

Some notable improvements you might want to make

- The default thread pool is very small.  It's equal to the number of CPU cores on the system.  Creating your own `ForkJoinPool` instance will give you greater control.
- Moving to a separate class for launching and parsing args would be much better.